# Advanced field path creation in Spring Boot microservices using Java/Kotlin

Tags: java, spring, kotlin

I am working on a Spring Boot microservice application using Kotlin, where I have developed a library that includes essential features and configurations shared across all of my Spring services. To optimize query development for MongoDB, I have implemented a dynamic field path builder. Instead of hardcoding paths like "owner.name.firstName," I utilize a builder pattern that leverages reflection or strings, as shown below:

```
MongoField.init(Product::owner)
      .nested(Person::name)
      .nested(PersonName::firstName)
      .build
```

While this approach offers structure and flexibility, I find that hardcoding paths can be more straightforward for readability. I'm exploring if there's a way in Java or Kotlin to combine the benefits of both approaches, particularly by incorporating advanced features like field validation and autocompletion.

Is there a way that allows me to create field paths using a hardcoded style, but with added validation and autocompletion capabilities? My ideal solution would involve real-time validation, highlighting erroneous fields in red, and providing autocompletion suggestions for valid fields, similar to modern code editors.

For example, when the correct path is "owner.name.firstName" all fields are in the valid colors, and when I type this path "owner.na.firstName," where "na" is not correct, the editor marks it as an error and prevents me from building the app.